# Split a string around characters in python

Tags: python, string, list, loops, split

Hey guys I have seen on here answers to how to split strings at a specified character and that's pretty simple. What I need to know is how to split strings between 2 characters

i.e splitting for character strings beginning with M and ending in Z
RERTCRPVNMVRNSRRTNSKSRSRHRZGRCRCGRHWVRNFDNPFISRYRRSZTSFFIFTVKFLSSYGLKKRKIKRTTVKVQGSTIMSLLNTZLN

into
RERTCRPVN
MVRNSRRTNSKSRSRHRZ
GRCRCGRHWVRNFDNPFISRYRRSZTSFFIFTVKFLSSYGLKKRKIKRTTVKVQGSTI
MSLLNTZ
LN

and later only keeping those desired.

I might be able to form some kind of weird loop to do this like

```
NET=Aminos.split('M')
LIST=[]
rock= int(0)
while LIST[rock]!= 'M' and LIST[rock]!= '':
    LIST.append('M' + NET[rock])
    rock=rock + 1
    other=other+1
print(LIST)
```

but in this given example I get the index out of range error.

This sort of thing seems rather tedious as well because I would have to break LIST apart after each Z with a split and try to concatenate 'Z' to the end of each.

Does anyone know of a way of doing this more efficiently?

Comment: for context sake what I am trying to do here is identify open reading frames

Comment: Feel free to accept an answer if you find it useful, or elaborate if not. I notice none of your questions have accepted answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to extract all strings beginning with M and ending with Z from a string:

```
>>> re.findall('M.*?Z', "RERTCRPVNMVRNSRRTNSKSRSRHRZGRCRCGRHWVRNFDNPFISRYRRSZTSFFIFTVKFLSSYGLKKRKIKRTTVKVQGSTIMSLLNTZLN")
['MVRNSRRTNSKSRSRHRZ', 'MSLLNTZ']
```

Or, if you want to keep the strings in between as well:

```
>>> re.split('(M.*?Z)', "RERTCRPVNMVRNSRRTNSKSRSRHRZGRCRCGRHWVRNFDNPFISRYRRSZTSFFIFTVKFLSSYGLKKRKIKRTTVKVQGSTIMSLLNTZLN")
['RERTCRPVN', 'MVRNSRRTNSKSRSRHRZ', 'GRCRCGRHWVRNFDNPFISRYRRSZTSFFIFTVKFLSSYGLKKRKIKRTTVKVQGSTI', 'MSLLNTZ', 'LN']
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something for `re.split`:

i.e.:

```
import re
ex = re.compile("M.*Z")

splitted = re.split(ex, <some input string>)
```

**Edit:**
Updated per Tim Heap, as I misinterpreted "beginning with M and ending in Z" as occurring at word boundaries.

**Edit 2:**
After @Cairnarvon's feedback, here is an example that works (surprisingly, `re.split` doesn't accept the result of `re.compile`, you must pass in the regex as a string:

```
>>> s = "RERTCRPVNMVRNSRRTNSKSRSRHRZGRCRCGRHWVRNFDNPFISRYRRSZTSFFIFTVKFLSSYGLKKRKIKRTTVKVQGSTIMSLLNTZLN"
>>> ex = re.compile("(M.*?Z)")
>>> re.split(s, ex)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 167, in split
    return _compile(pattern, flags).split(string, maxsplit)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
>>> re.split("M.*Z", s)
['RERTCRPVN', 'LN']
```

Comment: You probably want to remove the word boundary '<' and '>' bits, as the M.*Z string appears to be embedded in another word with no word boundaries around it.

Comment: Thank you, @TimHeap, I misinterpreted the question.

Comment: Without a capturing group, this will discard the MZ strings, and a greedy match will always split out the widest possible string.

Comment: @Cairnarvon, good point...next update coming in a few moments, after I actually test.

Comment: `re.split` takes a string as its first argument, but a compiled regex object has a `split` method, if you really want to use a compiled regex.

Comment: I believe my solution is now correct given the problem statement: "i.e splitting for character strings beginning with M and ending in Z RERTCRPVNMVRNSRRTNSKSRSRHRZGRCRCGRHWVRNFDNPFISRYRRSZTSFFIFTVKFLSSYGLKKRKIKRTTVKVQGSTIMSLLNTZLN", however, I think the example result is incorrect, or does not accurately describe the problem.